# Extract the first occurence from a string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with a `contentEditable` attribute and I struggle to extract the first text occurence from a string.

I am using `innerHTML` to get the text from it( I need to use it, can not use `innerText` or `textContent`) and it comes with a lot of `<br>`.

The string will be something like this:

'`<br>` This is some text `<br>` `<br>` Another piece of text'. I need only the text('`This is some text`') without `<br>`.

The string will always have `<br>` in it and the place of the `<br>` may vary.

I tried using the `replaceAll('<br>', '')` and it returns `'This is some text Another piece of text'` but I need only the first occurence `'This is some text'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.split()` to divvy up the content by `<br>`, then run that through a simple filter that will remove any empty items in the array, and finally choose the first item in the array, which will be the text you want.

```js
let fragment = document.querySelector('div.content').innerHTML.split('<br>').filter(a => a.trim())[0].trim() ;
console.log(fragment);
```

```html
<div class='content'>
<br> 
<br> <br> 
This is some text <br> 
<br>
<br> This is some more text <br> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as I want it too!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function getFirstNonBlankSubstring(text, separator) {
  const array = text.split(separator);
  for (const substring of array) {
    if (substring.trim()) {
      return substring;
    }
  }
}
```

`getFirstNonBlankSubstring(element.innerHTML, '<br>')` should give you what you need **as long as you can count on the `<br>` tags looking exactly like that.**

If you can't, you may need to walk the DOM to find text nodes.

Comment: It works exactly as expected but so is Kinglish answer and he was the first to answer so I accepted his answer. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, I appreciate it.

Comment: Array.prototype.map is not lazy, so Kinglish's answer will continue parsing the string after it's got what it needs. That said, if your innerHTML isn't huge and it's more understandable to you then I agree it's a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can doit like this

```
//get the text and remove white space from left
var readText = document.getElementById("content").textContent.trimLeft();

//How many splits you want out    
var freeSpaces = 3;
//
var splittext = readText.split(' ');
var newText = splittext.slice(0, freeSpaces);

//final text
var finalText = newText.join(' ');
```